# RSA public key generated in Java is not valid in php

Tags: java, php, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption, php-openssl

I'm creating a RSA key pair in Java and want to use it in PHP. Java code is as follows:

```
public static boolean keyGen() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, OperatorCreationException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    KeyPairGenerator kpGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");  
    kpGen.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());  
    KeyPair keyPair = kpGen.generateKeyPair();  

    PublicKey pub = keyPair.getPublic();
    byte[] pubBytes = pub.getEncoded();
    SubjectPublicKeyInfo spkInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(pubBytes);
    ASN1Primitive primitive = spkInfo.parsePublicKey();
    byte[] publicKeyPKCS1 = primitive.getEncoded();
    PemObject pemObject = new PemObject("RSA PUBLIC KEY", publicKeyPKCS1);
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(stringWriter);
    pemWriter.writeObject(pemObject);
    pemWriter.close();
    String pemString = stringWriter.toString();
    FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream("pubk.key");  
    fos2.write(pemString.getBytes());  
    fos2.flush();  
    fos2.close();
}
```

The generated public key looks like follow:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAh8cQcRitRdEIzcWDpgDhGTxU4e/4CnFcCi4pEi8Pitme4+9MlVOQ
EtwpiaH54nbxBLZX6m/Z0EETqE9hJm02L8cgvp6/T08atJ9NAayEkN5TFSgdmh3Y
CwGa0ckHlO1lzN3jghUTxLnYEHOvBXVaY1SpDEUlLUi6WKsyklqHK+r6fPa9X1sY
6847VPTQX8ORC13LEzdZrGSR39473HTBhR6SzyTET47AgHPy2Q+FMIvN7DeuX5dK
XtQUlvAjJ7KVQJIXuFEzNvHQfUzjJj+LO2MHX77KbGg6Ytz06CnsWS2f6YKBY3Bg
BQ2zqjE2ON1jDLUcika+2ihEzpfXFGLY9wIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

And I'm importing the saved key file using PHP as follows:

```
 $keyString = file_get_contents($filePath);
 openssl_pkey_get_public($keyString);
```

And when try to encrypt using `openssl_public_encrypt`  it gives me the error

> openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key

However I tried the same with a JavaScript generated key file and it works well. Any help?

Comment: Something is wrong in your description. You are outputting a **public key** in Java, then claiming you successfully called `openssl_pkey_get_private(...)` on it and only received an error when you tried to use this key.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Thanks, that was a mistake. It should be `openssl_pkey_get_public(...)`. I edited the question. Any hint?

Comment: What does `$keyString` look like?

Comment: Also, show your PHP code. How are you trying to encrypt? What are you doing with `openssl_pkey_get_public`?

Comment: @miken32, Hi, I'm just using the `file_get_contents()` to read the generated key file from the above Java code.

Comment: But what does it look like?

Comment: Looks like you got an answer. That’s what I was going to say. You need a public key with “PUBLIC KEY” header instead of “RSA PUBLIC KEY”

Comment: @miken32 yeah, it worked. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key evidently needs to be in SubjectPublicKeyInfo format, sometimes referred to as "X.509" format -- but not the same thing as an X.509 certificate -- just to add to the general sea of confusion. I got this info not from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-public.php) but from the user comments below.

Fortunately this takes even fewer lines of Java code to produce, as this little code fragment adapted from your code illustrates:

```
    PublicKey pub = keyPair.getPublic();
    byte[] pubBytes = pub.getEncoded();
    PemObject pemObject = new PemObject("PUBLIC KEY", pubBytes);
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(stringWriter);
    pemWriter.writeObject(pemObject);
    pemWriter.close();
    System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
```