# Converting a Java encryption method to Php

Tags: java, php, encryption, phpseclib

I am trying to generate an encrypted message to send to a remote server and when I do it in Java I succeed but when I try it in PHP, I fail. 
I would like your help in pointing out where I am going wrong in the php version. Below is the Java and php version of my code.

```
 private String encryptMessage()  {
    String msg = "";
    String message = "this is the message to send";
    String modulus = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String exponent = "111";
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    RSAPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(modulus, 16), new BigInteger(exponent, 16));
     KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
     PublicKey publicKey = factory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
     Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "BC");
     cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
     byte[] messageDataBytes = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF8"));
     msg = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(messageDataBytes).replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");

    return msg;
 }
```

The php version that fails

```
    private function encryptMessage()
{
    $message = "this is the message to send";
    $modulus = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $exponent = "111";
    $rsa = new RSA();
    $exponent = new BigInteger( $exponent, 16);
    $modulus = new BigInteger($modulus, 16);
    $rsa->loadKey(['n' => $modulus, 'e'=>$exponent]);
    $rsa->setPublicKey();

    $publicKey = $rsa->getPublicKey();
    openssl_public_encrypt($message, $encryptedData, $publicKey);
    return base64_encode($encryptedData);
}
```

For Java,I am using the Bouncy Castle Library while I am using phpseclib version 2 library.

Thanks.

Result from the Java method: VU06XTAFfNfBSjhWz+deqVt/cZw7YBG1nfl0g/c8GwInVTiW1oOwX53z2+Sxp3o65kNztwRSA4ARVKjnrH4M/ygJ+9jrHLvKWt2mmKbcTF9tkmd3Ezdd429s44azulFNRwH0lqQNy80mPTpNzRN4QDkeuRp1mUqDlNHQ70T7BdWwCvjMXZ/kBjXEHocYE+fNmXjgxCQFDCkek1CZQ+IDvxRyW5MtsuQDzAphUO3Kj5epMTJkzUuekV1RzCUErerfUUb83HAo3hh6IGuqhSw3MKjVY7g7AlO0P/0n1pI2+fi/g0EojK7MJt8mzx/WrWxQH2fiMo0GuTb4+YB4+YS9dQ==

Result from PHP:
U1pWl/ohAkP+1+L25vCMwVeQ3bkRJwwWocDn/lWgIkFYM6V8/Wn+LHVbm/ku0ZV0we1tXUkQE784xH7q7Cd9h4P2mGA5XWHdtGHTzQaxHgT31DN/60I5rDsC8A3OJORNbJk/6rBh8PuDEi33vqtayE7v4rqIYXTxAwDWUgjvnBtJOQtZXgfhrnCb/jKiLP5WY2yBfa5/3eHoLCtmButGy2GgrEmg08OnvJlqSTQd/Xtc+1NhWVlha8+vk2e/rZZn/aOzvYAOoUZQbWRUhlonObfom/1HtRJrBJGfJxv2zLFNPP6RrDgoYptMhsNs4r8OVSxj6qiEYFx9tjNqp9c1xA==

Comment: You need to show us a sample value and the output each of these function generate and specify which is the correct output

Comment: What makes you think that the Java method is a success and the PHP is a fail? They both look successful.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk 
The result is sent to a server and its accepts the Java version while it rejects the PHP version.

Comment: Does the server provide any clue about why it rejects it? Perhaps an error message, or an exception stack trace?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. It just tell me the encrypted data has an error.

Comment: Could you post the public key modulus and exponent so that we can reproduce the issue? Also, why are you doing `openssl_public_encrypt`? Why not use phpseclib to do the encryption? eg. `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1); return base64_encode($rsa->encrypt($message))`. I mean, you can do whatever, but it does feel kinda silly to switch it.

Comment: Hi @neubert,  I tried using $rsa->encrypt($message) but that also didn't work.

Comment: Can you post the public key modulus and exponent so that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, terms and conditions of the API is that I can't share those details with anyone.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer or maybe a solution for your problem? If yes we need a little bit more information about the modulus and the exponent that are given in Java and PHP - what kind of data is it (I assume it's a hexstring "12abcd34" and not a numberstring "12345678" and not a Base64-encoded one).

Comment: Hi @MichaelFehr, I went around the problem by building a small Java app just to get around this scenario. The exponent is actually a number string.

Answer (score 0):

My solution consists of 3 files to get a complete testing environment with full working encryption and decryption in Java
and encryption only in PHP.

The test environment I'm working on is on Java-side 11.0.6+8-b520.43 (without any dependencies, e.g. Bouncy Castle)
and on PHP-side php version 7.4.6, openssl version: OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020 and phpseclib 2.0.27.

**GenerateKeysSo.java**: generates an RSA private/public keypair in modulus/exponent-presentation. I use the **insecure 512 bit keylength** just to keep the string length a little bit shorter - in production you should use a **minimum of 2048 bit keylength**.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.util.Base64;

public class GenerateKeysSo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        System.out.println("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53947613/rsa-public-key-generated-in-java-is-not-valid-in-php");
        System.out.println("Generate RSA keys");
        System.out.println("java version: " + Runtime.version());
        KeyPairGenerator kpGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        //kpGen.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
        kpGen.initialize(512, new SecureRandom()); // don't use 512 bitlength as it is insecure !
        KeyPair keyPair = kpGen.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        byte[] privateKeyEncoded = privateKey.getEncoded();
        byte[] publicKeyEncoded = publicKey.getEncoded();
        RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) privateKey;
        RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) publicKey;
        BigInteger modulus = rsaPublicKey.getModulus();
        BigInteger privateExponent = rsaPrivateKey.getPrivateExponent();
        BigInteger publicKeyExponent = rsaPublicKey.getPublicExponent();
        System.out.println("privateKey   Base64: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(privateKeyEncoded));
        System.out.println("publicKey    Base64: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKeyEncoded));
        System.out.println("modulus            : " + modulus);
        System.out.println("privateExponent    : " + privateExponent);
        System.out.println("publicExponent     : " + publicKeyExponent);
    }
}
```

The result is short and you need to copy the 3 values of modulus, privateExponent and publicExponent with copy/paste to EncryptSo.java and to
EncryptSo.php:

```
Generate RSA keys
java version: 11.0.6+8-b520.43
privateKey   Base64: MIIBVAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT4wggE6AgEAAkEAgKpP+4e9D3r5Mbw4VBaQQG/LRw7nqDOWOU6p+teU2c+mTPE2apPzYUku9AaNf+BiPyjzmkWh/9d7E5jUDWfS9QIDAQABAkA9Ia5y0eFwE3uGt+kDetz64KLylhBXCHudqtR0TC169s4UfGr6EquaqX9YKmQ4ApC5mkO65Rha8V0WzV6PEUlBAiEA6XtDObkbbhAMaDXpLkzqu0I5O2e3cpTMGwCTaK/0GVkCIQCNExoakOZ1+0f5UuiztmGo7UqBpZEieiybL25H/iI2/QIhANPubzcWLy/YoWp2hRLh/q+7jPe/TWVUa3CXNTbxgEEBAiAyA22jsW8isJ0JlQ0OeUASJV3erJXRhUK/GYedWklC+QIgLnxzZVDSNNEGYFpUER0v2bIFWqVXlnm87y5LRbzWn/I=
publicKey    Base64: MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAICqT/uHvQ96+TG8OFQWkEBvy0cO56gzljlOqfrXlNnPpkzxNmqT82FJLvQGjX/gYj8o85pFof/XexOY1A1n0vUCAwEAAQ==
modulus            : 6738747659637003090018178263545882875809887577706500222853194115214616163418986509701683514500084328991941041539147237736316411294805049495944982937719541
privateExponent    : 3201720015041533823900789397901821886674218828976379815054133670438877551559197501362784700723343540531608097210070472157677675484894343978127401531033921
publicExponent     : 65537
```

File 2 is the encryption/decryption routine in Java (**EncryptSo.java**). Paste the 3 values from GenerateSo to the three string variables modulusString,
privateExponentString and publicExponentString. Run the program and it will encrypt a message and decrypt it. After running the PHP-encryption (file 3)
you have an output there - you can paste this output to line 42 (variable ciphertextFromPhp). This string will get decrypted as well.

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class EncryptSo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException {
        System.out.println("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966418/converting-a-java-encryption-method-to-php");
        System.out.println("encrypt and decrypt with Java with key generation via modulus and exponent");
        String modulusString = "7655411376708364139873444642436134423578239360576333940175884244078181837546293928220019721607335417517025652060442851820596480386882812189086919617782503";
        String privateExponentString = "6181379361775076881056852519774102589787650800051550108278185489542231510128103539355646657479306697213227070361180012317478947328351699562861534356668225";
        String publicExponentString = "65537";
        BigInteger modulusBI = new BigInteger(modulusString);
        BigInteger publicExponentBI = new BigInteger(publicExponentString,10); // 10 = numeric string
        BigInteger privateExponentBI = new BigInteger(privateExponentString,10); // 16 = hex string
        // generate private & public keys
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPrivateKeySpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(modulusBI, privateExponentBI);
        PrivateKey privateKeyBI = factory.generatePrivate(rsaPrivateKeySpec);
        RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulusBI, publicExponentBI);
        PublicKey publicKeyBI = factory.generatePublic(rsaPublicKeySpec);
        // encryption
        String message = "this is the message to send";
        System.out.println("message Original : " + message);
        String ciphertext = encryptMessageEnc(message, publicKeyBI);
        System.out.println("message encrypted: " + ciphertext);
        // decryption
        String decryptedtext = decryptMessageEnc(ciphertext, privateKeyBI);
        System.out.println("message decrypted: " + decryptedtext);

        System.out.println("decryption of a encrypted message from PHP");
        String ciphertextFromPhp = "B3a1v8oGVYqRpRwRwGP5KRaqaNiiXFRfTdWnz0LsI4Ek63BpXIrWsEXsVNaj1jSu4XIQNrvYHIpwdxwKQrBUUfXXwq6Pix0YfuOmz7mUJMyTerHMcVzcXIpEGAD/L0gGomfCbkahed/CimThPSO527ulazHVirOY173JjMTrWdqyFLS6L7sCD6UHkU49gW94ADkOJtRXOiIWTg==";
        System.out.println("message encrypted: " + ciphertextFromPhp);
        decryptedtext = decryptMessageEnc(ciphertext, privateKeyBI);
        System.out.println("message decrypted: " + decryptedtext);
    }
    private static String encryptMessageEnc(String message, PublicKey publicKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        String msg = "";
        //Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "BC");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        byte[] ciphertextBytes = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF8"));
        msg = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ciphertextBytes).replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
        return msg;
    }

    private static String decryptMessageEnc(String msg, PrivateKey privateKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        //Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "BC");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        byte[] message = Base64.getDecoder().decode(msg);
        byte[] messageDataBytes = cipher.doFinal(message);
        return new String(messageDataBytes);
    }
}
```

output of EncryptSo:

```
encrypt and decrypt with Java with key generation via modulus and exponent
java version: 11.0.6+8-b520.43
message Original : this is the message to send
message encrypted: WZs0jp6yMWR71I4g7Oxo54A28yDZRBs5usKYLz9NfoRkMPy7vpe+riLSZzr6mdC8XZFNGveH9HsG2maZWSxhsw==
message decrypted: this is the message to send
decryption of a encrypted message from PHP
message encrypted: B3a1v8oGVYqRpRwRwGP5KRaqaNiiXFRfTdWnz0LsI4Ek63BpXIrWsEXsVNaj1jSu4XIQNrvYHIpwdxwKQrBUUfXXwq6Pix0YfuOmz7mUJMyTerHMcVzcXIpEGAD/L0gGomfCbkahed/CimThPSO527ulazHVirOY173JjMTrWdqyFLS6L7sCD6UHkU49gW94ADkOJtRXOiIWTg==
message decrypted: this is the message to send
```

File 3 (**EncryptSo.php**) is simple PHP-application that builds the public key via modulus and exponent and need the external dependency "phpseclib". I included the library without any composer-help just manually. Paste the modulus and exponent to the variables modulusString and publicExponentString and let it run.

```
<?php
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966418/converting-a-java-encryption-method-to-php
include('phpseclib\Math\BigInteger.php');
include('phpseclib\Crypt\RSA.php');
include('phpseclib\Crypt\HASH.php');
echo 'php version: ' . PHP_VERSION . ' openssl version: ' . OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT . ' phpseclib 2.0.27' . PHP_EOL;
$message = "this is the message to send";
$modulusString = "7655411376708364139873444642436134423578239360576333940175884244078181837546293928220019721607335417517025652060442851820596480386882812189086919617782503";
$publicExponentString = "65537";
$rsa = new \phpseclib\Crypt\RSA();
//$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$exponent = new phpseclib\Math\BigInteger($publicExponentString, 256);
$modulus = new phpseclib\Math\BigInteger($modulusString, 256);
$PUBLICKEY = "";
$rsa->loadKey(['n' => $modulus, 'e'=>$exponent]);
$rsa->setPublicKey();
$publicKey = $rsa->getPublicKey();
openssl_public_encrypt($message, $encryptedData, $publicKey);
$encryptedData = base64_encode($encryptedData);
echo PHP_EOL ."encryptedData base64: " . $encryptedData . PHP_EOL;
// encryptedData base64: K4DCBvi2lWbyQJGiQbZ9cXiZy49sg+Q0KKPvj7+TMObTCyWKtoQce8pmUJlDZ48+K1Fy3vHtTTZFDQzr7fkWKoeYffl171IsxOgFLz2bmjQYhrNiLy5ZI03qUX4i9MI0mtSMlITXhiryDOajHB61Cgs5cfgH+yVCJItV7cM/qMBAGnQVqoMxRAKaSOBEz/zxp3If5X9Jb5zuhA==
?>
```

Result of PHP encryption:

```
php version: 7.4.6 openssl version: OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020 phpseclib 2.0.27
encryptedData base64: M5ys/5JrlleQO5MJDVl6FvRcIUIcxXQhp00y/KLHfB1p0XRNaVaWRwV9t5NKoJmo4wKI1KQI1H9PBd71c6t3i7IWsWcS8QsebOk5iitacvgOTJBW71pjrzWkv4+M7Ge8KZ/jhCl6nQ+e9zNSkJf4HZE1NHmOzFan3pBN1gXDptj19AZPue/MxqdAIgDD538UElvhTzyWMpCJeA==
```